# Opencart create new 2 different customer login

Tags: php, authentication, opencart

I am creating a e-commerce in opencart. And now I need to create a login for 2 different customers.

1. The customer who would like to shop online.
2. The customer who pays their saving amount through online.

2nd specified customer should be able to log in and view their payment history.

so how I can implement this in opencart. I almost done it for online shopping. But I am now stuck with this 2nd option.

How I can create a another login page in opencart?

Comment: You need to extend login controller as per your requirement or create new login function from controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added a button. where we have to add button fuction

Answer (score 0):

**For create/add custom controller**
Please note that these are basic steps. You need to change / add / update code as well as per requirement.

- create new file under **catalog > controller > account >**
- name it as you want, like payment_login.php or anything you want.
- You can use same code from login.php and change it as per your requirement.
- You also need to create template files if you wish to display output in different page / view

**For extend controller / model**
I stronglly recomed to use VQMod and do not change core files.
More information on VQMod is here. [VQMod Docs](http://docs.opencart.com/administration/vqmod/)

- Create new function in **Catalog > controller > account > login.php**
- Same way repeate for **system > library > cart > customer.php**
- You need to add condition in customer.php or you can set that condition in login.php controller as well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution